# How to make enemy move back and forth

Tags: python

Below are 2 functions of enemies for 2 levels in a game. The first one works well but `def moveEnemy2()` doesn't. The enemy appear stuck in place, when its suppose to move back and forth horizontally. It also tremors slightly, so I'm not sure if its an error with the boundaries or..

The part of code for the enemy movement is as follows:

```py
def moveEnemy():
    global diry
    for enemy in enemies:
        if enemy.top<200 or enemy.top>450:
            diry =- diry
        enemy.top -= diry

def moveEnemy2():
    global dirr
    for enemy2 in enemies2:
        if enemy2.left<500 or enemy2.left>100:
            dirr =- dirr
        enemy2.left -= dirr
```

enemies in level 1&2 are in a list:

```
enemies=[Rect(200,350,60,34),Rect(640,300,60,34)]
enemies2=[Rect(200,470,60,34)]
```

dirr and diry are also defined:

```
dirr=1
diry=1
dirr2=1
diry2=1
```

Comment: In moveEnemy2, your if statement is checking if it less than 500 or greater than 100. This can never be false. Did you intend to be checking if it is less than 100 or greater than 500?

Comment: Yes. The goal of that line is to make the enemy turn around if it goes over 500, and turns around if it goes under 100.

Comment: If `dirr = -dirr` activates every frame, your enemies will appear to oscillate back and forth in place, moving a tiny bit to the left, then a tiny bit to the right, etc. (so the fix is what Colin said, flip the conditions of the if statement)

Comment: so make it "if enemy2.left>500 or enemy2.left<100:"?

Answer (score 0):

The condition in `moveEnemy2` always evaluates `true`. The correct condition is `if enemy2.left < 100 or enemy2.left > 500:`. To avoid such mistakes in the future I suggest to use [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```py
if not (100 < enemy2.left < 500):
    dirr = -dirr
```